Simple problem of optimizing a positive definite matrix
I am working on writing a simple tutorial about constrained optimization. I plan to use two examples: constraining a vector to have unit norm, and constraining a matrix to be symmetric positive definite. I want to have some very simple examples of such optimizations with synthetic data.
For example, for the unit-norm constrain, I generate random samples of a distribution on the unit circle, and them optimize a vector $\theta$ that minimizes the average squared distance to the samples. When not constraining $\theta$, the result is not in the unit circle, and adding the constraint, we get a $\theta$ in the unit circle.
I'm trying to think of a similarly simple and intuitive problem involving optimization of some matrix $\Sigma$ that should be positive definite. However, I can't think of anything as simple and clear cut. For example, if we wanted to do as above and find the matrix that minimizes the distances to a set of positive definite matrices, the unconstrained result would be positive definite. I thought of having a loss function that pushes $\Sigma$ towards a non SPD matrix, but then I suppose that the optimization procedure would not converge.
So, my question is, what is some simple well-behaved optimization problem over matrix $\Sigma$ where it is intuitive why we would have it be positive definite, and where it would not be positive definite if we don't include a constrain in the optimization? I would like to be able to synthesize data for my problem in not too much code within my tutorial.
Edit: I implemented the example suggested in the answer. See the result here https://dherrera1911.github.io/posts/2024/08/constrained-learning-with-pytorch-parametrizations/

A covariance matrix estimated with missing data need not be positive definite.  That is, suppose you have a data matrix $X$ with observations $x_{ij}$ and for some $ij$ the value of $x_{ij}$ is missing.  If you calculate the covariance of columns $j$ and $k$ using all the rows $i$ for which both columns are observed, you end up with an estimated covariance matrix $\hat\Sigma$ where different elements of the matrix are estimated from different sets of rows. It is possible for this matrix not to be positive definite or even positive semi-definite, although the true $\Sigma$ is positive definite.

Thanks, that's an interesting easy to understand example. One detail though is what loss I could use in the optimization for this case. I guess that maximizing the likelihood of the data under a Gaussian distribution, where for the rows with missing columns I use a reduced covariance that doesnt have those rows/columns?

to add to this answer, it is common to deal with this in estimating covariances from financial data.  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X17301343 covers techniques. I assume the sample covariance matrix is not well defined for that reason ( eg company shares not traded throiughout a given time period - some being created/some going bankrupt.

I implemented the example. It works like a charm. See the link to the post in the question. If you have any comments about the use of the example, I'd love the feedback
